# How should I register this type that has parameterized constructor, in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, tdd, unity-container

I am trying to register a type that has a constructor method like:

```
public Foo (int myNumber, IBar bar) {...}
```

I produce instance of IBar via Unity container.
How should I regsiter and Resolve the Foo?

Regarding to the example below, how can I replace the line new Foo... with a unity register and resolve way?

```
public interface IBar
{

  public void SayNumber();

}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public void SayNumber()
    {
        Coonsole.Write("Number : ");
    }
}


public interface IFoo
{
    void int GetMyNumberTimesTwo();
    public int MyNumber{get;}
    public IBar Bar {get;}
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{

    private IBar _bar;
    private readonly int _myNumber;

    public Foo (int myNumber, IBar bar)
    {
        _myNumber = myNumber;
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public void GetMyNumberTimesTwo() {return _myNumber * 2; }
    public IBar { get{ return _bar; } }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{

     var container = new UnityContainer();
     container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();

     // QUESTION: So how should I Register and Resolve the container to achive 
       //  the line below? 

      IFoo f = new Foo(999, container.ResolveType<IBar>()); // This should be replaced upon your answer

     Console.WriteLine(f.Bar.SatNumber + f.GetMyNumberTimesTwo());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register the type as

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new InjectionConstructor(999, typeof(IBar)));
```

Comment: I did in this way, I don't know there is a difference though: container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new InjectionConstructor(999, new ResolvedParameter<IBar>() ));

Comment: They are equivalent really, providing the type is a shortcut. You do need to use the ResolvedParameter when you want to resolve to a specific name, but when you don't need a name you can use either one.