# how to register parameterized based constructor classes in unity container in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container, loose-coupling

I am new to Dependency injection Pattern. Please look in to the below scenario. Right now, my below code is in tightly coupled. I want to make this as lightly coupled.

Could someone help me out to implement dependency injection using Unity?

```
// Implementation of class A
public class A
{
  public B b{get;set;}
  public A(B b,string c)
  {
     this.b=b;
     this.A(b,c);
  }
}

//Implementation of Class B
public class B
{
    public int value1 {get;private set;}
    public string stringValue {get;private set;}

    public B(int value,string strValue)
    {
       this.value1=value;
       this.stringValue=strValue;
    }
}
//Implementation of class C
public class C
{   
  public void Dosomething()
  {
     B b=null;
     string value="Something";
     // Here I need to implement unity to resolve tight coupling 
     // without creating  object of Class A
     A a=new A(b,value); 

  }
}
```

I tired something based on the blow possible duplicate question. But still I am facing same issue.

How should I register this type that has parameterized constructor, in Unity?

Instead of this line, I have implemented the below code

```
     A a=new A(b,value); 

var container=new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<A>();
container.RegisterType<B>();
A a=new A(b,container.ResolveType<B>();
```

But its not helping me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I register this type that has parameterized constructor, in Unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067496/how-should-i-register-this-type-that-has-parameterized-constructor-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would start be advising that you further decouple your classes by introducing Interfaces, so you could implement class C as follows:

```
 public class C
{
    private readonly IA a;

    private readonly IB b;

    public C(IA a, IB b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void Dosomething()
    {
        // do something with this.a or this.b.
    }
}
```

You could then register and resolve your classes as below:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IB, B>(new InjectionConstructor(1, "Test"));
        container.RegisterType<IA, A>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IB>(),"Test"));
        container.RegisterType<IC, C>();

        var c = container.Resolve<IC>();
```

Although I would recommend the above approach, as an alternative, you can also stipulate the injection values when you resolve, for example:

```
container.RegisterType<IB, B>();

container.Resolve<IB>(
            new ParameterOverride("value", 1), 
            new ParameterOverride("strValue", "Test"));
```